# Trying to send request to server with python socket library, I get a type error

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I seem to be getting a type error when I make a request to the server "www.python.org". I have just started learning networking and I am going over the basics. I understand why a type error itself would occur since a string was not expected, but based on the PDF tutorial I am reading, that is the format to make a request to the server, am I typing it wrong?? How do I evade the type error? Thanks. Code below:

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("www.python.org",80)) # connect
s.send("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n") # send request
data = s.recv(10000) # get response
s.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Python 3. In Python 3 string literals are unicode objects. Unicode objects cannot be sent over a network socket, only bytes can be sent.

The tutorial you are reading might have been written for Python 2, where string literals are bytes instead of unicode.

In Python 2:

```
this_is_bytes = "my string"
this_is_unicode = u"my string"
```

In Python 3 things were switched around to have unicode strings by default:

```
this_is_bytes = b"my string"
this_is_unicode = "my string"
```

You either need to encode the unicode string to bytes:

`s.send("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n".encode('ascii')) # send request`

Or use a bytes literal:

`s.send(b"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\n\n") # send request`